# Importing beneficiary records into DHIS2 tracker from Excel

Tags: data, dhis2, import

I am working on a project where we have about 80K (80,000) beneficiary records in an Excel spreadsheet.  Can I import this into DHIS2 tracker?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to import the data as long as the data elements match those in your DHIS2 tracker capture instance. However, you will need to use a script to import that data.

Comment: I'm also interested in importing tracked entity data. @Bridget are such scripts' templates published somewhere? it would be very helpful to import tracked entities data in bulk.